# jQuery Isotope order by number sorts items incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I set up Isotope order and sort on my site but if I change the ordering to number it sorts items wrong.

for example I have items like this:

```
<div class="boxm" data-name="aaa" data-number="11944"></div>
<div class="boxm" data-name="bbb" data-number="1494"></div>
<div class="boxm" data-name="ccc" data-number="1574"></div>
<div class="boxm" data-name="ddd" data-number="1892"></div>
<div class="boxm" data-name="eee" data-number="19520"></div>
<div class="boxm" data-name="fff" data-number="2090"></div>
<div class="boxm" data-name="fgf" data-number="9010"></div>
```

with the Isotope code like this:

```
$container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.boxm',
        masonry : {
            columnWidth : 67,
            cornerStampSelector: '.corner-stamp'
        },
        getSortData : {
            name : function($elem){
                return $elem.attr('data-name');
            },
            number : function($elem){
                return $elem.attr('data-number');
            }
        }
    });
$sortLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('selected')){
            return false;
        }
        var $isSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $isSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        var options = {},
            key = $isSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[key] = value;
        if(key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function'){
            changeLayoutMode($this, options)
        }else {
            $container.isotope(options);
        }

        return false;

    });
```

if I press order by number it will order the same as I typed in here and if I press sort by DESC than it will start with 9010 folowed by 2090. if I'm right this is because Isotope watches only the first two character but I need to order it correctly.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It is probably because that the value of the data-number attribute is not considered an integer value but a string. Try this:

```
number : function($elem){
            parseInt($elem.attr('data-number'), 10);
        }
```

Numbers stored in strings are sorted in a not always logic way, ie 199999 is less than 2 because of the initial digit.

(thanks balexandre for the comment about adding the base)

Comment: Thanks, now it looks much better :) but it still makes mistakes like: after 1990 comes 1330 and than 2000 and 1600 so on but almost good :D Maybe its because of the masonry and the different size elements, don't know

Comment: Yes maybe. Can you see in your code view the actual orders of the HTML elements? Maybe floated elements seem unordered while they are actually not in the code?

Comment: originally the php loads the elements orderd by name ASC from database so the html code is ordered by name and in the Isotope container I have only the elements which I want to sort.

Comment: Yes but do you have a tool like Firebug or Chrome dev tool then you will see the dynamically altered source of the document. Just viewing "source" in your browser doesn't help you, you need to see how the DOM changes. Then you can see if the order is correct or not.

Comment: to make this correct, always append the base when using `parseInt`, in this example, you should write: `parseInt($elem.attr('data-number'), 10);` - [Isotope Docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html#sortascending_option) mention this as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
getSortData : {
            name : function($elem){
                return $elem.attr('data-name');
            },
            number : function($elem){
                return $elem.attr('data-number');
            }
        }
```

You are returning a string here

change return `$elem.attr('data-number');` to return `parseInt($elem.attr('data-number'));`

This should solve the issue.