# Isotope filter by price not working when into the hundred thousands

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have an isotope filter for properties. When sorting by price anything that has 6 digits moves out of price order and to the beginning. For example the order shoulde be 46,000 52,000 98,000 112,000. Instead the 112,000 comes first.

I'm assuming its only reading the first couple or few digits so is seeing that the 1 should come first.

How can I tell it to sort in a monetary value?

Here is the code I'm using -

```
$( function() {
  var $container = $('.full-wrapper');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        itemSelector: '.development-tile',
        masonry: {
        isFitWidth: true

    },

  getSortData: {
    name: '.tile-title',
    price: '.tile-price'
  }
});
```

Comment: maybe isotope sortby? http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html

Comment: I have looked through the documentation but cannot see any reference to my issue unfortunately. The sorting is working, just not properly with numbers with 6 digits...

Comment: this so answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773164/jquery-isotope-order-by-number-sorts-items-incorrectly

Comment: Hi Marco, sorry I should have explained what I had tried. I have used this code but it breaks my entire sorting. I was hoping someone could make suggestions based on my existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for your numbers:

```
$( function() {
var $container = $('.full-wrapper');
$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    itemSelector: '.development-tile',
    masonry: {
    isFitWidth: true

},
getSortData: {
name: '.tile-title',
 price: function( itemElem ) {
    var price= $( itemElem ).find('.tile-price').text();
    return parseFloat( price.replace( /[\(\)]/g, '') );
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Ah ha! I tried this previously but it broke the sorting entirely. However, I realised my £ was part of the number it was filtering. I've removed the £ and now it sorts perfectly. Thank you.